# What should be the choice of arguments of the branch cuts of multivalued complex functions..

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

While we consider branch cut of a multi-valued complex function like log(z), should we consider the arbitrary choice of branch cut as

0 < theta <2π

Or

0<=theta<2π.

Please provide the reason.

Comment: See [the plot on the right](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_point#Complex_logarithm) representing all the possible branches of $\log z$

Comment: I do understand branch cut. I am asking do we need an equal to sign or not, when considering branch cuts. I feel we need an equal to sign. Some books write [,] closed set, some write [,) such a set some mention (,) set for the angles. I want this to be clarified which is correct way.

Comment: You do as you want. But if you start with *"take a branch of $\log$ analytic on $\mathbb{C} \setminus (-\infty,0]$ and $\log (1) = 0$"* and you mention $\log (x)$ for some $x < 0$, then you'll need to precise its value (and say if you take it as $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+}\log (x+i\epsilon)$ or $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+}\log (x-i\epsilon)$ or anything else)

Comment: I meant for angles (0,pi] etc... sorry if I do not know the terminologies, I am not a mathematician.

Comment: Do you understand what I wrote ?

Comment: From what you wrote, I understand that you are talking about inclusion of branch point in the branch cut. However, I am talking about inclusion of the branch cut in the single valued domain. Should the branch cut be excluded when talking about single valued domain, or should the branch cut be included.

Comment: I said you do as you want. If you start with *"the branch of $\log$ defined by $\log(r e^{it}) = \ln r+ it, r > 0, t \in [0,2\pi)$"* then it is clear what you mean.